# How to escape apostrophes from user input

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, escaping

So I'm importing information from a .csv file into a database. However I'm having trouble with the user inputted description in the csv file as they contain apostrophes which is breaking the SQL import.

My Import statement is String sqlJob =

```
"INSERT INTO job (ID, Job_Contact, Internal_Comment, Customer_Name," 
  + " Duration, Job_Location, Job_Completion_Date, Job_Technician," 
  + " Job_Asset, Job_Type, Job_Description) VALUES ('"
  +csvRecord.get(i)+"', '"+csvRecord.get(26)+"', '"+csvRecord.get(16)
  +"', '"+csvRecord.get(2)+"', '"+csvRecord.get(31)+"', '"+csvRecord.get(27)
  +"', '"+csvRecord.get(28)+"', '"+csvRecord.get(29)+"', '"+csvRecord.get(30)
  +"', '"+csvRecord.get(33)+"', '"+csvRecord.get(34)+"');";
```

A simplified form would be

```
"INSERT INTO job (ID, Description) VALUES ('"
  + csvRecord.get(i) + "', '" + csvRecord.get(34) + "');";
```

The problem is `csvRecord.get(34)` will sometimes contain apostrophes. For example "My name's Bob" and that apostrophe in Bob is breaking the surrounding apostrophes that are needed to declare that the value is a string for the SQL.

Is there an easy way to parse the string and add escape characters in front of apostrophes or should I format my original SQL command a different way.

Thanks!

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @TheImpaler's answer mentions this and a solution to it, but "SQL Injection" is the main problem you're faced with when trying to roll your own character escaping code. It's safer and ultimately easier for you if you use libraries that can manage parameters for you.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is you are assembling the SQL statement as a String, concatenating the parameter values. This is highly not advisable.

Use `PreparedStatement`s instead that are easier to use. You can pass parameters without any modification and they won't interfere with the correct execution of the SQL statement.

Also as a valuable bonus, your code will be free of SQL Injection problems.

Example from the [JDBC Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
String updateString = "update COFFEES set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
PreparedStatement updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
updateSales.setInt(1, numSales);
updateSales.setString(2, coffeeName);
updateSales.executeUpdate();
```

As you see, the parameters are NOT concatenated into the String, but they will take the place of the `?` symbols.

Even if `coffeeName` has the value `"Africa's Best"` (apostrophe included) the query will work well.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! I wasn't quite sure the purpose of prepared statement, but this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use **PreparedStatement** so you can be in save.

```
 String name = request.getParameter( "ID" );
        String message = request.getParameter( "Job_Contact" );

        Connection c = null;
        try
        {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/**"databasename"**;
            String username = "**<Database Login>**";
            String password = "**<Database password>**";

            **// at the ? section you can add any quantity you need to**

            String sql = "insert into **<databasename>**(name, message) values (?, ?)";

            c = DriverManager.getConnection( url, username, password );
            PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement( sql );
            pstmt.setString( 1, name );
            pstmt.setString( 2, message );
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new ServletException( e );
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if( c != null ) c.close();
            }
            catch( SQLException e )
            {
                throw new ServletException( e );
            }
        }
```